# in laravel how to accept ascii charset request

Tags: laravel-5

I am receiving parameter like

{url}?BODY=%00d%00e%00u%00d%00a%00s%00+%00q%00u%00e%00+%00h%00a%00b%00%ED%00a%00+%00r%00e%00q%00u%00e%00r%00i%00d%00o&TIME=2017-07-05+15:18:40

the characters are in ASCII/UTF-16BE encoding how can I get correct text of BODY parameter in laravel

Comment: Is the `urldecode()` function a thing like in php?

Comment: I tried it I am receiving body like BODY=�d�e�u�d�a�s� �q�u�e� �h�a�b���a� �r�e�q�u�e�r�i�d�o

Comment: it is giving me correct text

Comment: text is like *deudas que había requerido*

Comment: explode("&",str_replace('%00', '', $BODY))[0]

Comment: not working deudas+que+hab%EDa+requerido

Comment: how can i replace %ED with  í in a single line